# How do I access remote files using emacs running locally?

Tags: networking, ssh, emacs, remote-access

Normally, to edit my files, I need to ssh into host `sunfire` and on that host, I need to ssh into another host `xcnc1`. My files are on `xcnc1` which I can only access through `sunfire`.

My question is how can I access that `xcnc1` files from my local machine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Tramp with ad-hoc proxies. Something like `C-x C-f /ssh:user1@sunfire|ssh:user2@xnc1:/path/to/file`. If `user1` or `user2` are the same user as your local one, you could omit them.

Comment: Nice, upvoted; and clearly better than my earlier answer which I nixed.